# How to access VBA code from outside the Excel file?

Tags: excel, vba

I implemented a password dialog box at the beginning of opening the file. Wrong password or closing the dialog leads to

```
Application.Quit
```

by mistake at queryclose event I also make it close the application with

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    'Here I should check type of close
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```

What I've now closes the application if it's correct because the dialog unload and calls queryclose automatically, otherwise wrong password prompt.

I can't access the file. How can I edit the VBA code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you hold Shift whilst clicking open the file it will open without running macros:

http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/preventopenevent.asp

Answer (score 3):

What about changing the extension from xlsm to xls? That is non macro enabled and should not execute itself automatically, you can also open any other excel and do the file--> options--Trust center--> settings and disable all mcaros in Macro setting tab.

Comment: it's another accepted solution thank you, I've already opened it by holding shift at opening as toom advised .

Answer (score 0):

Holding shift did not work for me. Trust Center may be unavailable for some users on domains. What can work is surprisingly simple, though: renaming the file and running it. Excel will treat it as a new file and block macros there by default (if security center is setup this way, though).